# Is there a way to get all data of third level children in laravel without the use of loops using eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
Category::where('parent_id',0)->with(['children' => function($query){
            $query->with('children');
```

Using this i will get all the categories starting from the first level to the third level. but i only want compiled third level categories. 
Is there any way to do it without looping the data?

Comment: Unless you mapped the children separately with level data, you can not derive it directly.

Comment: ok thanks.. Was just wondering if there was any other way.